# PreparedStatementSetter issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Why is my code importing last row twice? Every row is ok from zero to x, and then is added the last row one more time..

```
@Override
public void batchUpt2(User_FK users) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO INS_RAZNO.BULK_TEST VALUES (?, ?, ?)", new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            int x;
            int size = users.getUser().size();
            for(x = 0; x < size; ++x) {
                ps.setInt(1, x + 1);
                ps.setLong(2, users.getUser().get(x));
                ps.setInt(3, users.getSys());
                ps.addBatch();
            }ps.executeBatch();
        }

    });
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;
    System.out.println("-------------"+duration+"-----------------forEach");

}
```

I have this "user":[1,2,3,4,5,6] in argument but 7 inserts. Result is in rows 1,2,3,4,5,6,6

Comment: @AdityaNarayanDixit That won't make any difference.

Comment: Tried but is the same..

Comment: If the user size be e.g. 10, then you should be seeing 10 inserts.  Are you _not_ seeing 10 inserts?  If not, then how many do you expect?

Comment: I have this "user":[1,2,3,4,5,6] in argument but 7 inserts. Result is in rows 1,2,3,4,5,6,6

Comment: I think you should check your API documentation and make sure that your current batch insert syntax is valid with `PreparedStatementSetter`.

Comment: API documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementSetter.html  and https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter-

Comment: You can start by check the result of the batch.  `executeBatch` return an array, this will give for each "query" the result. So based on what you have, you should find an array of 6 cells but your result seems to have 7cells. Which is it ? What are you exactly printing to validate this ? Is your table empty to begin with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final solution which is working.

```
@Override
public void batchUpt2(User_FK users) {


    long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < users.getUser().size(); i++) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO INS_RAZNO.BULK_TEST VALUES (?, ?, ?)", new Object[] {
            i+1, users.getUser().get(i), 1  
        });
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;
    System.out.println("-------------"+duration+"-----------------forEach");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe last user is added twice in the source list. Can you check by printing size of source list in setValues()

Comment: No, its very precise, because this is on test level. Have only 6 values for input.. and 7 as result.